# Is there a way to change the number of classes while using imagedatagenerator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am currently working with my own dataset that has 4 classes (cat, dog, mouse, tuna) and so far I am able to classify between those 4 classes fairly good.

I want now to change the problem into "Classify between Mammal and no Mammal" but I cant find a way of doing so without changing the way the images are stored on each folder.

I've come up with this method that is not really efficient:

```
def to2Clases(image_generator,batch_size):
  noMammal= (0,0,0,1,)
  for x, y in image_generator:
    for i in range(len(y)):
      
      if all(y[i]==noMammal): y[i] = (0,1,0,0,)
      else: y[i] = (1,0,0,0,)
  yield x, y
```

I could, for example, predict using the original classes and when needed, transform the prediction but I think that it would be the same problem that I've been working from the beginning

Does someone know a better way of doing this?

**Another Method**

The only "Solution" that I was able to find uses Mnist data set and transform the problem into a binary classification (even/odd)

```
even=[0,2,4,6,8]

        #Converting Train labels from numbers to even/odd
        Y_trainbinary= np.empty(Y_train.shape[0],dtype=object)     
        for idx, item in enumerate(Y_train):                     
              if np.nonzero(item)[0] in even:
                    Y_trainbinary[idx] = 0     # even number
              else:
                    Y_trainbinary[idx] = 1     # odd number

        Y_trainmodel = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_trainbinary)
```

This solution doesn't really work for me, because MNIST uses label encoding while my train generator uses one-hot encoding.

**Additional info**

This is how I define my train_generator

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    vertical_flip = True,
    validation_split = 0.1)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_train,
    target_size = (img_height, img_width),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    shuffle = True,
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    subset = 'training',
    seed = 42)
```

And here I print y to see it's shape:

```
x,y = train_generator.next()

print(len(y))
print(len(y[0]))
print(y[0])
```

This is the output:

32 (batch size)

4 (number of classes

[0. 1. 0. 0.] (tuple)

Comment: I'm not sure if there is enough here to provide a definite solution. But from the looks of it you're still trying to define your target classification/category as 4 possible classes (cat, dog, mouse, tuna) instead of 2 possible classes (mammal, not). // A weak guess, but try setting the `y[i]` equal to either `(1, 0)` or `(0, 1)` to represent one-hot mammal versus not mammal classes.

Comment: @KDecker the problem is that I cannot change the shape of y[i] since it's a tuple. I tought that changing it to be just the first two classes the model would never predict another class

Comment: Instead of `yield`ing `y` then just pass back the tuple you need, i.e. `(1,0)` or `(0,1)`, based on the value of `y`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come to a solution and I want to post it in case someone has the same problem.

First you have to forget about using "Flow From Directory" when creating the generator, instead use "Flow From Dataframe".

To create a dataframe you can use the following code:

```
lst = list(data_train.glob("*/*.tiff"))
newLst = list() 
print(lst[0])
for l in lst:
    if l.parent == data_train / "bird":
      type="Not Mammal"
    else:
      type="Mammal"
    newLst.append((str(l),type))

df = pd.DataFrame(newLst, columns = ['path', 'category'])
print(df)
```

This way you can change the name of the category (one thing that you are not able to do while using directories).

You then use (almost) the same code to initialize the generator:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    vertical_flip = True,
    validation_split = 0.1)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    df,
    x_col = "path",
    y_col="category"
    target_size = (img_height, img_width),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    shuffle = True,
    class_mode = 'binary', 
    subset = 'training',
    seed = 42)
```

So far it works the same way as flow from directory.